# trying to sort data in text box in php and save to text file

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, text

hi there i am trying to create a php script to extract data inbetweeen dilems and save it in a text file

the data is like so

```
data 0 | Data 1 | data 2 | data 3 | data 4 | data 5 | data 6 
data 0 | Data 1 | data 2 | data 3 | data 4 | data 5 | data 6
```

heres my script i am using

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
<div align="center"><textarea name="mp" cols="60" rows="10">0|1|2</textarea><br />

Delim: <input type="text" name="delim" value="|" size="1" />&nbsp;data1: <input type="text" name="mail" value="0" size="1" />&nbsp;data2: <input type="text" name="pwd" value="1" size="1" />&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value=" send " name="btn-submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mp'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
    $a = $_POST['mp'];
    $myFile = "t.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $a);
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

i want it to basically grab the data i select so if i select dilem as `|` the section 3 and 5 
it should save the data like this `data 3:data 5`

but instead it is saving all the data please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort data in array using php and dilems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677470/sort-data-in-array-using-php-and-dilems)

Comment: Please don't repost exactly the same question.

Comment: What?  What do you want to do?  Its not clear at all?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [**Stack Overflow question checklist**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
     <html>
  <body>
      <form method="post">
  <div align="center"><textarea name="mp" cols="60" rows="10">0|1|2</textarea><br />

  Delim: <input type="text" name="delim" value="|" size="1" />&nbsp;data1: <input type="text" name="mail" value="0" size="1" />&nbsp;data2: <input type="text" name="pwd" value="1" size="1" />&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value=" send " name="btn-submit" />
  </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['mp'], $_POST['delim'], $_POST['btn-submit'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
      // separate the value into an array of newlines
      $delim = $_POST["delim"];
      $lines = explode("\n", $_POST["mp"]);
      // get the indexes that have the data you want
      $email = $mp[$_POST["mail"]];
      $password = $mp[$_POST["pwd"]];
      // open the file
      $myFile = "t.txt";
      $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
      foreach ($lines as $line){
        $row = str_getcsv($lines, $delim);
        fputs($fh, $rec[$email].":".$rec[$password]."\n");
      }
      fclose($fh);
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: @ash This should be the merged solution with [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681960/php-sorter-script-only-outputting-the-same-data-even-though-i-am-asking-it-to-do/17682165#17682165)